# How to make navbar not overlap content? Navbar-static-top works, but does not make it fixed-scrollable

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have a problem with my navbar. I'm currently using asp.net.

When I use the class navbar-fixed-top, the navbar becomes fixed-scrollable (shown at the top upon scrolling down the page), but the navbar overlaps the content in the contentplaceholder

Then, I change the class to navbar-static-top, the navbar doesn't overlap the content anymore, but the navbar does not become fixed-scrollable anymore.

How do I make it such that my navbar scrolls down with my page, yet does not overlap my content?

Here are my codes:

```
div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top navbar-default " style ="color:white" id ="content1">

        <div class="container" style ="color:white">
            <div class="navbar-header" style ="color:white">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div class ="navbar-brand" style ="font-family:'Bradley Hand ITC'; font-weight:900; font-size:300% ; color:white">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Shoppo" runat="server" OnClick="Shoppo_Click" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" ValidationGroup="B">Shoppo</asp:LinkButton> </div>
             <!--   <a class="navbar-brand"  style ="font-family:'Bradley Hand ITC'; font-weight:900; font-size:250%" runat="server" href="~/Welcome">Shoppo</a> -->

            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="font-family:Calibri; color:white; font-size:120%" aria-disabled="False" aria-hidden="False" aria-live="off" aria-required="False">
                <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="Womens" runat="server" OnClick="Womens_Click" ForeColor="#FF3399" ValidationGroup="B">Women's</asp:LinkButton></li>
                            <li>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="Mens" runat="server" OnClick="Mens_Click" ForeColor="#0099FF" ValidationGroup="B">Men's</asp:LinkButton></li>
                            <li> <asp:LinkButton ID="Search" runat="server" OnClick="Search_Click" ForeColor="White" ValidationGroup="B">Search</asp:LinkButton> </li>
                            <li> <asp:LinkButton ID="Register" runat="server" OnClick="Register_Click" ForeColor="White" ValidationGroup="B">Register</asp:LinkButton></li>
                            <li>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="Login" runat="server" OnClick="Login_Click" ForeColor="White" ValidationGroup="B">Login</asp:LinkButton> </li>
                        </ul>

                    </AnonymousTemplate>

                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %>!</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </LoggedInTemplate>

                </asp:LoginView>
           </div>
            <div class =" row " style=" border: 20px; color: white">
     <div>     
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div> 
    </div>
            </div>

            </div>



    <div class="container body-content" >
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <hr />
        <footer .....
```

Comment: Please, provide a fiddle!

Comment: what's a fiddle? @TeutaKoraqi

Comment: Fiddle is an online editor, you can put your css, js ad html code, and run your code. You can save your edits, and copy that link and provide here. Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Have you added padding (equal to the height of your navbar) to the body tag?

*Your CSS should include something like...*

```
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I added that - it worked in full window, but as I resized the window to become smaller, the navbar still overlaps the content.

Comment: Hi, I made the navbar collapsible so it helped. Thanks!